# Windows Docker Python Path

Tags: python, django, docker

I was successfully able to run my container (Django Python) on an older version of the docker engine. I did not change any code, yet now I see this error.

```
$ docker run --net container_net --ip 172.18.0.2 sift_pro
python: can't open file './manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is what my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.8


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install
...
...
...

COPY . .

CMD  ["python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"]
```

I have also tried other variations of this code with no success.

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR c:\\windows\\sift

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


COPY . .

CMD  ["python", "C:\\windows\\sift\\manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"]
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```